# API REST with CodeIgniter and AngularJS (get working; delete, save and update not working)

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, rest

I'm building an API REST with CodeIgniter 3 and AngularJS following this video. The video is in Spanish, but it's a great material: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjXpVJi6pHY.

I cannot figure it out why am I able to retrieve the books (it's a little books database that we are making as an example) from the database. But I'm not able to remove, edit or add them.

Focusing, at the moment only on deleting a book:

If I click on the first book from the list I get:

```
DELETE http://localhost/codeigniter/restangularjs/books/1 400 (Bad Request)
```

And if I click on the second book on the list I get the same error, just with number `2` at the end.

So the system knows which controller to call, and even passes it the correct id of the book (number 1 for the first book and number 2 for the second book).

Below I'm attaching all the relevant files that are needed for deleting a book. I don't know where to start and would appreciate some guidance.

I find it strange that in the factory named Book (the only factory in app.js) we only define `update` (used in the EditCtrl). But we do not for example define `save` (used in CreateCtrl), `delete` or `get` (both used in HomeCtrl).

On the other hand it seems to me that as we are dealing with a REST_Controller (Books.php is not a CI_Controller, but a REST_Controller) `update` could work for all the calls (so not just for update, but also for save, delete and get).

I'm even more inclined to that option as the function Books.get (inside HomeCtrl) ...

```
Books.get(function(data){
    $scope.books = data.response;
});
```

... is the only function that is working properly, even though there is no `get` call inside the factory.

But I don't know. I really don't know. This is my first API REST.

My tree (on xampp/htdocs with the relevant folders and files only):

```
codeigniter
--restangularjs
----application
------controllers
--------Books.php
------models
--------Books_model.php
angularjs
--ciangularrest
----src
------index.html
------app.js
------components
--------list.html
```

CodeIgniter - extract from Books.php (controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . "/libraries/REST_Controller.php";

class Books extends REST_Controller 
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Ne vem, če je spodnjo vrstico header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); varno pisati - fora je v tem, da z zvezdico daš dostop vsem. Preveri.
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
        if($method == "OPTIONS") {
            die();
        }
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('books_model');
    }

    public function index_get()
    {
        $books = $this->books_model->get();

        if( ! is_null($books))
        {
            $this->response(array("response" => $books), 200);
        } else
        {
            $this->response(array("error" => "No books available"), 404);
        }
    }

    // Other functions here but not relevant for my post on StackOverflow

    public function index_delete()
    {
        if( ! $id)
        {
            $this->response(NULL, 400);
        }

        $delete = $this->books_model->delete($id);

        if( ! is_null($delete))
        {
            $this->response(array("response" => "Book deleted"), 200);
        } else
        {
            $this->response(array("error" => "There was an error"), 400);
        }
    }

}
```

CodeIgniter - extract from User_model.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Books_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get($id = NULL)
    {
        if( ! is_null($id))
        {
            $query = $this->db->select("*")->from("books")->where("id", $id)->get();
            if($query->num_rows() === 1)
            {
                return $query->row_array();
            }
            return NULL;
        }

        $query = $this->db->select("*")->from("books")->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where("id",$id)->delete("books");

        if($this->db->affected_rows() === 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

AngularJS - extract from app.js

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', 'Books', '$route', function ($scope, Books, $route) {

    Books.get(function(data)
    {
        $scope.books = data.response;
    });

    $scope.remove = function(id)
    {
        console.log("inside remove function; " + "deleting the book with id=" + id);

        Books.delete({id:id}).$promise.then(function(data)
        {
            if(data.response)
            {
                $route.reload();
            }
        })

    }

}])

.factory('Books', ["$resource", function($resource){

    return $resource(
        "http://localhost/codeigniter/restangularjs/books/:id", 
        {id:"@_id"}, 
        {update: {method: "PUT", params: {id: "@_id"}}}
    )

}])
```

AngularJS - extract from list.html

```
<a ng-click="remove(book.id)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: You want us such a long code to debug? Asking debugging help is off-topic at SO.

Comment: I see the problem, yes. But how else am I to present the problem that I have? Do you think it would be a good idea to extract from the code examples only the lines that are relevant. In that way my post would be much much shorter. I've included all relevant code because I thought it is better that way than not adding something important.

Comment: Ok, I've deleted the code that is not directly connected to the problem. I've  left only the code that has to do with getting and deleting books.

Comment: `http://localhost/codeigniter/restangularjs/books/1` this is wrong link.This should be `http://localhost/codeigniter/restangularjs/books/index/1`

Comment: again your index_delete function should be like this `public function index_delete($id)` otherwise from where you getting `$id`?